# conditional statement not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove a div if the page is 'our-values' or is a singular custom post type of 'work'.

I'm using this code:

```
<?php if( !is_singular('work') OR !is_page('our-values') ) : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

However, for some reason it's not working when I add the OR. If I try them individually then it works but together they don't work.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: did you try with `||`  instead od `OR`?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that and still didnt' work

Comment: should be AND instead of OR - Right now you are hitting everything - because if it is `work` then it still isn't `our-values` - change it to `&&`

Comment: Hi Stender, that's worked

Comment: If you submit an answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: Cool -. just did that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments :

In your case, you got the logic wrong :

should be `AND` instead of `OR` - Right now you are hitting everything -

because if it is `work` then it still isn't `our-values` -

change it to `&&` and it will work

Good luck to ya mann!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AND` in your scenario

Comment: Yes Indeed. That is my job, to sit and read the comments which are posted almost at the same time as my answer.

Comment: I was obviously kidding ;) Take my upvote and love me again! </3

Comment: Too late, I declared the war first